# 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id'

Tags: php, mysql

Hi: I'm having trouble debugging some MySQL & PHP code.

**Background**

- Downloaded http://ajaxlivesearch.com/ source code
- Followed instructions and enabled debugging
- Created a MySQL db with the following columns: list_ADDRESS, list_COMPANY, list_WEBSITE, list_INDUSTRY
- I know the db + connection work (I set up a small test file to connect & spit out the tables that're in the db)

**Issue**

- The search doesn't work and returns a 'Something went wrong' error
- With debugging enabled, the error_log file shows the following:

> [26-Aug-2015 06:37:42 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'' in /public_html/inz/class/handler.php:85
>   Stack trace:
>
> 0 /public_html/inz/class/handler.php(85): PDO-prepare('SELECT COUNT(id...')
>
> 1 /public_html/inz/ajax/process_livesearch.php(21): Handler::get_result('Telecom', 1, 5)
>
> 2 {main}

- handler.php (around line 85) contains the following code:

> $db = DB::getConnection();
>
> *//this is line 85//* $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ' . Config::USER_TABLE . ' WHERE ' . Config::SEARCH_COLUMN . ' LIKE :query');
>   $search_query = $query.'%';
>
> $stmt->bindParam(':query', $search_query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
>
> $stmt->execute();
>
> $number_of_result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

- For ref, process_livesearch.php line 21 contains the following:

  ```
          $result = json_encode(Handler::get_result($_POST['ls_query'], (int) $_POST['ls_current_page'], (int) $_POST['ls_items_per_page']));
  ```

Does anyone know why it seems to be looking for a column called 'id' ? That's not specified anywhere in the config file, nor elsewhere in the code that i can see other than being mentioned on line 85 of handler.php...

Comment: add an id column to the table and set it to be unique

Comment: The error is telling you everything you need to know: `column id is missing`. Add it :)

Comment: Show your  table 'Config::USER_TABLE'
Whats columns it included?

Comment: Thanks @Ohgodwhy - the search now works! New problem: it doesn't find items that are in the database. I will do some more digging and see what happens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To eliminate this particular error you could change `count(id)` to `count(1)` in your query.

Comment: Thanks - this has also helped: it now at least returns a result (albeit empty result) which is more than it was doing once the 'id' column had been added.

Comment: Consider this answered by @Your Common Sense - I can't mark it answered yet :)